# What is the phi matrix in SEM?

Tags: r, structural-equation-modeling, confirmatory-factor

How is it found in the output?

I am trying to do confirmatory factor analysis using sem function in R.
Everything works fine, except I don't know how to obtain phi matrix.

Below is my model specification:

```
F1 ->  S1, lam1, NA
F1 ->  S2, lam2, NA
F1 ->  S3, lam3, NA
F1 ->  S4, lam4, NA
F2 ->  L1, lam9, NA
F2 ->  L2, lam10, NA
F2 ->  L3, lam11, NA
F2 ->  L4, lam12, NA
S1 <-> S1, e1,   NA
S2 <-> S2, e2,   NA
S3 <-> S3, e3,   NA
S4 <-> S4, e4,   NA
L1 <-> L1, e9,   NA
L2 <-> L2, e10,   NA
L3 <-> L3, e11,   NA
L4 <-> L4, e12,   NA
F1 <-> F1, NA, 1
F2 <-> F2, NA, 1
```

How can I get phi?

Comment: @Whuber - I've edited the question to make it more general.

Comment: I can also write an answer.

Comment: That would be great! I can't find phi matrix in summary and don't know how to get it

Comment: The way you've set uip the model, the phi matrix is an identity matrix (I think). It's the variances and covariances of the (exogenous) latent variables.  I'm not sure if sem concptualizes everything as a y-model or an x-model, but in this model you could call the latent variable variance-covariance matrix either psi (if you call the measured variables y) or phi (if you call the measured variables x).